# Two SQL non-clustered index creation

Tags: sql, indexing

I've got a fairly large table that I'm trying to add two non-clustered indexes to at the same time and it is taking a very long time to go through.

Both are set with ONLINE=ON so that the table data could still be updated and more rows added to it.

Two quick questions:

-I'm wondering if updating data in such a large table is causing the index to never fully be created?

-Now that I've stopped the table from being updated, should both indexes now be created or could they be interfering with each other? (ie. should I cancel one of them?)

TIA

Comment: To add to the last point I can see that both indexes are each actually increasing in size so I know that one is not being totally blocked over the other... more so wondering if they would or could get stuck in a loop with each other

Answer (score 0):

FYI, neither of them finished. I cancelled one and still the other didn't finish. ONLINE did not work at all, I had to revert to ONLINE=OFF and the indexes created fine.